# Можно мне создать некий "массив", на N елементов и что бы везде были 0?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
   myList.Add(0);
}
```

Очень сильно сомневаюсь что это оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Так вам нужен массив или список? Массивы всегда создаются заполнены нулями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив это `int [] myInt = new int[N];` и каждый элемент там точно равен 0 :)
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xg9sL6
Или можно вот так: `List<int> myList = new List<int>(new int[8]);`

UPDATED:

Или можно вот так:
`int N = 8;
List<int> myList = new List<int>(new int[N]);`

Comment: В new int[8] параметром должно быть константное значение, а нужно с переменной N.

Comment: Вместо 8, поставте вашу переменную :)

Comment: Да, правильный ответ. В CLR любая выделяемая память обнуляется. Поэтому преобразование массива в List полностью решает задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Сгенерировать повторяющееся значение можно при помощи `Enumerable.Repeat`. Получается так:

```
List<int> myList = Enumerable.Repeat(0, N).ToList();
```

---

Если хочется экстремальной оптимизации, то ваш код тоже подойдёт, только укажите capacity

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(N); // <-- capacity
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) myList.Add(0);
```

Но я бы не рекомендовал заморачиваться, если только это не кусок кода, к которому есть *очень* серьёзные требования по скорости.

Comment: Ну, как-то из пушки по воробьям :)

Comment: @MichaelVaysman: А чем плохо? Коротко и понятно.

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке не хватает перегрузки `ToList()` с параметром `capacity`, очень часто требуемая вместимость известна заранее и можно было бы неплохо сэкономить. Впрочем такой метод не трудно написать самостоятельно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: И то правда, был бы полезный метод.

Answer (score 0):

Почему же? не так уж и плохой вариант, разве что неудобен в плане написания. Но можно написать отдельную функцию для этого.
Насколько мне известно в List нет функций позволяющих сделать это быстро и просто.

Comment: А если не List?

Comment: обычные массивы изначально заполнены нулями (насколько помню)

Comment: @BogdanBida разве O(n)? Это разве не список с массивом внутри? Тогда там немного другая сложность заполнения, учитывать над операции реаллокации...

Comment: Ах, да, точно! 
Но все же, с другой стороны, это не такой уж и плохой способ. Хотя не спорю что возможно есть какой то обходной костыль, или полноценный рабочий метод

Comment: @BogdanBida там есть конструктор, который инициализирует List с нужной начальной емкостью

Comment: @selya есть конструктор, но он принимает Capacity, а это нечто иное от Count

Comment: @Kotsiuba я и сказал - начальная емкость. Т.е. размер внутреннего `backing array` - массива внутреннего крч. Тогда операции `Add` будут выполняться n раз, и это все займет `O(n)` времени, пока не будет достигнут `Capacity`. После будет переаллокация внутреннего массива с увеличением его размера.